# Debug games from steam with PIX

Tags: debugging, directx

Do you have any solution to debug games with PIX (from directx) from my steam library ? Not every game won't work when it doesn't start by steam process :/

Answer (score 2):

I would pretty much doubt you could without going through steam. From what i have experienced the executable for the game you try to run contains code that interfaces with steam (an API). I guess it would be pretty redundant to allow a DRM controlled game to be able to run freely or in this case be debugged.

Answer (score 2):

Add a file to the game's main folder (where the primary exe is located) called "steam_appid.txt" and write the game's Steam ID in it. After doing this most Steam games can be launched directly using the primary exe.

I used this same trick with PIX and Steam while programming an injected DirectX game addon that works with any DirectX game.

Answer (score 1):

You might have some success by injecting a DLL such as this
[Steam Debug](http://www.wowsharp.net/blog/11-08-07/Steam_s_anti-debugging_code.aspx)

One of the main issues lies in the fact that there is a ThreadHideFromDebugger flag used within the OS. These are countermeasures to prevent users from hacking the code and stopping users from cheating.

I certainly hope that you are trying to debug through a legitimate issue and not trying to circumvent the system. 
Using measures such as these can and will get you banned from the network, so use this at your own discretion.

These are other sources straight from Valve that should assist you in fixing your issues.

[Valve Debugging](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Installing_and_Debugging_the_Source_Code)

[Valve Command Line options](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options)

Comment: The program the OP wishes to use is PIX. PIX is generally used to look through calls to DirectX so I don't believe any other debugger would be too useful in this case nor do I believe PIX would be useful either.